# JS using array from external source file

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a web application built in Javascript. I'm using PHP to output a directory list as a json_encoded array into a text file. I'm then using JS to get the text file and load it into a variable thats expecting the array, however, i get an error about 'unexpected [' or it outputs each letter o the text file as an array item;

I need to output the following (this works if i type this in directly);

```
var $images = ["artwork1.png","artwork2.png","artwork3.png","artwork4.png","artwork5.png","artwork6 copy.png","artwork6.png"];
```

my text files reads

```
var $images = ["artwork1.png","artwork2.png","artwork3.png","artwork4.png","artwork5.png","artwork6 copy.png","artwork6.png"];
```

And my JS that i'm using is

```
var file = "system/.cache/gallery_array.txt";
$galleryArray = "";

$.get(file, function (txt) {
$galleryArray = txt;
var $images = $galleryArray;
}
```

If i copy the array into my code, it works, but can't get it to recognise the array in the text file when accessing via variable.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to remove `var $images = ` and end semicolon from text file.

Comment: ...or just include the file normally with `<script>`.

Comment: If remove the var and semicolon from the text file, the text file reads: 

["artwork1.png","artwork2.png","artwork3.png","artwork4.png","artwork5.png","artwork6 copy.png","artwork6.png"] 

I then get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [

Comment: *Where* exactly do you get that error? Which line?

Comment: It's Pulling the error from Jquery;
'Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ['  jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2

Comment: @epascarello - is that to use getJSON instead of my current method of loading the text file re $.get?